# cognitoUser.signOut() is not a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to singout a user form cognito service. Following is the logout function that i have written.

```
async getCurrentUser() {
  const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: config.UserPoolId,
    ClientId: config.ClientId
  });
return userPool.getCurrentUser();
}

async logout(req, res) {
  return new Promise((success) => {
    const cognitoUser = this.getCurrentUser();
    if (cognitoUser !== null) {
      cognitoUser.signOut();
      res.redirect(req.query.redirect_uri);
    }
   success();
  });
}
```

Here, **cognitoUser.signOut()** even I call this signOut(), it gets this error.

```
 TypeError: cognitoUser.signOut is not a function
```

So how i can i resolve this. Or is there any way to signout the current user from cognito service?

Comment: Which Cognito JS library are you using? Is it being imported properly?

Comment: @NickK9 I have used "amazon-cognito-identity-js" library

Comment: That library was [archived 4 years ago](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js). Amazon now recommends [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/) instead. You should seriously consider using the modern library for new projects.